# Excel setting validation range for multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where in columns are recipes and in rows parameters for those recipes, something like:

[image]

Is there any simple solution to add validation for each row (the first cell is parameter name so it must be skipped) based on the min &max list with those parameters in another sheet? The number of columns may vary in the future.

I figured out something like:

```
 With Selection.validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="=param_limits!B5", Formula2:="=param_limits!C5"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "zakres"
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "0  do 9999999"
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Formula1 and Formula2 are cells with max and min value for this parameter.

But I don't have any idea how to change ***Selection.validation*** object for exact row and how to iterate through sheet until the last parameter. Could someone show how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: to iterate, you can do loops with `For...next`. And to change Selection.validation, replace `Selection` with target range. Something like `Range("B2").Validation`

Answer (score 0):

I figured something like and it works fine:

```
For Each cell In Sheets("B").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2))
        minLimRange = "=param_limits!B" & cell.Row
        maxLimRange = "=param_limits!C" & cell.Row
        InputMsg = "Od " & Range(minLimRange).Text & " Do " & Range(maxLimRange).Text
         With Range(Cells(cell.Row, 2), Cells(cell.Row, LastColumn)).validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
            :=xlBetween, Formula1:=minLimRange, Formula2:=maxLimRange
            .IgnoreBlank = False
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = "Zakres wartości"
            .ErrorTitle = "Wartosć poza zakresem"
            .InputMessage = InputMsg
            .ErrorMessage = "Wpisz wartośc zgodnie z zakresem"
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
End With
Next  cell
```